# Three.JS: Rotating Camera, Changing LookAt

Tags: camera, three.js

We recently started working with Three.js and we are facing some difficulties with OrbitControls.

We want to change the OrbitControls in such a matter, that instead of rotating the point around the target, we want to rotate the camera itself. Essentially changing what it is looking at.

Did anyone encounter such a request in the past?

Comment: Try setting the camera very close to the target and `controls.enableZoom = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 'dummy' camera and apply orbit controls to it. After the orbit controls are updated you can copy the rotation of that camera to another camera through which you render.